# Yo CorDapp on Corda Enterprise gives MissingMigrationException

Tags: corda

I am using Corda Enterprise 3.1 and trying to move the vault from H2 to Oracle 12c using the Database Migration tool supplied. I have made the changes in the `node.conf` configuration using values I know work to connect from IntelliJ. The driver is Oracle's `ojdbc8.jar` that came with Oracle SQL Developer. I have the [Yo! CorDapp](https://github.com/corda/yo-cordapp) installed on the node.

However, I get the following error when I try and start my node:

> [ERROR] 2018-08-07T22:43:32,666Z [main] errors.errorAndExit - Failed
> to create datasource. Please check that the correct JDBC driver is
> installed in one of the following folders: - /apps/team/drivers/jdbc
>
> Caused By
> net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.MissingMigrationException: No
> migration defined for schema: net.corda.yo.YoState$YoSchema v1
>
> net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.MissingMigrationException: No
> migration defined for schema: net.corda.yo.YoState$YoSchema v1 at
>
> net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.SchemaMigration.doRunMigration(SchemaMigration.kt:90)
> ...

Answer (score 2):

When installing a CorDapp developed against Corda Open-Source on a Corda Enterprise node, you need to provide a Liquibase migration script for each of the CorDapp's `MappedSchema`s.

The steps are as follows:

1. Deploy the CorDapp on your node (by copying the JAR into the `cordapps` folder)
2. Find out the name of the MappedSchema containing the new contract state entities
3. Call the database management tool: `java -jar corda-tools-database-manager-3.1.jar --base-directory /path/to/node --create-migration-sql-for-cordapp com.example.MyMappedSchema`

   - This will generate a file called `my-mapped-schema.changelog-master.sql` in a folder called `migration` in the node's base directory
   - If you don’t specify the actual MappedSchema name, the tool will generate one SQL file for each `MappedSchema` defined in the CorDapp
4. Inspect the file(s) created in the `migration` folder in the root directory to make sure it is correct

   - This is a standard SQL file with some Liquibase metadata as comments
5. Create a JAR containing the `migration` folder (conventionally it would be named `originalCorDappName-migration.jar`), and deploy this JAR together with the CorDapp (e.g. run the following command in the node base directory: `jar cvf /path/to/node/cordapps/MyCordapp-migration.jar migration`).

You can read more about this process here: http://docs.corda.r3.com/database-management.html#node-administrator-installing-a-cordapp-targeted-at-the-open-source-node.

Comment: i am getting same error when I try --execute-migration/--dry-run command. I have followed exactly the same steps. i got success in generating schema files and make it jar and deployed under /node-basedirectory/cordapps/  folder and try to run these command.  Error message:Failed to create datasource.
Please check that the correct JDBC driver is installed in one of the following folders:
       
Caused By net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.MissingMigrationException: <<specified some schema file name>> i have checked the schema file for error and completely removed the dependency.

Comment: Hi Joel kindly advise we got stuck with this issue we are not able to bring the node up we are getting missingMigrationExcetion always though we followed above steps